# How to enable shutdown via VNC

Tags: vnc

I've set up my Raspberry Pi to work without a monitor, and I access it via VNC.

The menu doesn't give me a shut down option any more, so I have to shut down via command line.

When I plug in a monitor I'm able to shut down via the menu - how can I enable shut down over VNC?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

The X session that you see is running in user space. You will need privileges to shutdown. If you start an X session using `xinit` or `startx`, it will not allow you to shut down either. You may only logout (xfce). If you start an x session from a display manager like gdm, lightdm, xdm, mdm etc, the X session is running with some privileges. command line is the best you can do.

Alternatively, you can write a script with `gksudo poweroff` It shall ask you for your password and shall proceed with the shutdown. You can place a shortcut on the desktop or as an applet in your taskbar.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to enter your password each time, you can add an entry to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: As suggested- making a shortcut is the simpliest. What OS are you using ?